# How can i add four blanks in the head of everyline in vim?

Tags: vim

Here is my file to edit in vim ,how can i add  four blanks in the head of everyline?
i can do it just as save `mypython.py` and use

```
sed  's/^/    /'  /mypython.py
```

how can i do it in the vim?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know the way of substitution in vim, do a `:h :s`,

```
:%s/^/    /g
```

(sgmart's answer) is pretty straightforward. and your question is very easy (as easy as you do it with sed) problem for vim.

If you were "lazy" don't want to learn vim too much, you could keep doing your shell way within vim:

```
:%!sed '/^/    /'
```

Now you get it, you have full power of sed, awk, (cut, paste, join....) in vim.

Answer (score 2):

When editing `myphyton.py` with `vim`, use:

```
:%s/^/    /g
```

in command mode

Comment: You don't need the `g` flag since there will only be one substitution per line.

Answer (score 1):

Select all lines using `v`, then press `>` for indent. Make sure your `shiftwidth` is 4 spaces and `set expandtab`.

Comment: Instead of using visual mode, you can also just do `gg>G` in normal mode.